# Is it possible to create a dynamic 1 byte file in Linux?

Tags: files

I want to create a file to which I can send information, which can be read out by using `cat`. If the data is not read out immediately, it should be lost. So the file size can be 1 byte at most. Also, there should not be an EOF when catting it.

So it should be something like `/dev/random`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/random
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 aug 30 12:16 /dev/random

$cat /dev/random
�Zd<'у�Ɇ��[7"$�T`g/��F��?���n��a���-�`�
�ս�"'�F����z��
               ����]�7/ۆs���Ha�bO�EY'NJ���gɠ������R:�u�E��#_�����ۀ�]�;6�������ό2�����GE9$E^xeE�����J���;
                                    K~�����צ�d0�b��$I��8 a��0<4��$]m5"�o�V�V-�s�p�|�
     �lB�(�O�4�=B�%�q�Gv[����IS�S)"y���
�q�*�a���$�)����J�}��ȍ|���cj�sD ���+�D9��=>�
G�؋���P�hiA��l�$H'��;]JB��?a:gc�����/6�қ�S{��Z]�,�8a޹�K�v
                                                              ��86t\���!+�xح���ȕ��3J
�������G,t�5+�s\}�PY������%��t�:������/�^�F�F�$`��{a�n+ș9;�����] �$���ϒ�L(����qX~��DE�
                  v
                   g�z����YI���Ӈ2���xQra�ryNcd�rF��F���k���/�����6  �X��5�����*F�?��I��0(W��yS��Qa�j��/�m�í$ů���eC}WC�Ƚ�#)��
                                                         G�U��+;�V�}�To�����p��R���[=�rv@�a��J�gv���r�t�mW+b4e
                                  aIg;
�SI�����fXSPE��m$�]X���-�(��S<��V/���I���p��գ'�A�����v�UnT5���zwv��a��f��.�v�Ji�n<�|^C
...
...
...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For what purpose? Perhaps a named pipe will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/random is not a normal file, it is a device file and is handled by the kernel. You can create other device files with `mknod`, but they can only have the behaviour of existing device files known by the kernel.

In order to get custom behaviour you are going to have to write your own kernel driver. [This guide](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html?page=1) shows you how to write a very basic kernel driver, from there you just need to modify it to write data written to it into a 1 byte into a circular buffer, and print out this buffer when a read is called on it.

Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve there may be an easier alternative to this approach.